# How can I subtract two elements (type float) in a row using map and a lambda function

Tags: python-3.x

I have this curiosity that im trying to kill but i dont know how.
Im trying to subtract to two elements in a row in a list with the type float using map and a lambda function.

```
li = [12.12,14.11,43.32]
```

Im doing this but it appears type float not subscriptable.

```
x = map(lambda y: y[1] - y[0], li)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without doing preprocessing of `li` (without outright abusing `map` just for the sake of using it). `map` is meant to operate on a single element at a time. To use it, you need to make sure that that single element has all the data you need to produce a new element.

Zipping the list with a shifted version of itself works to achieve this:

```
li = [12.12,14.11,43.32]

shifted = iter(li)
next(shifted)  # Drop the first element
neighbors = zip(li, shifted)

map(lambda pair: pair[0] - pair[1], neighbors)
```

Although, `lambda` isn't necessary here:

```
from operator import sub
from itertools import starmap

li = [12.12,14.11,43.32]

shifted = iter(li)
next(shifted)

neighbors = zip(li, shifted)

starmap(sub, neighbors)
```

`starmap` and `sub` make this far cleaner

Comment: And if I had a list like li = [(1.12,2.31),(3.32,1.32)], and i wanted to subctract the index 0 from the first element and the index 0 from the second element?